# Get traffic data on previous date

Tags: here-api

I didn't find how to get traffic data on previous date

```
https://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.1/flow/xml/8/134/86?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}&time=???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the given API is not providing historical traffic data. However you can raise a request to HERE and ask them for the traffic data for a specific time.